# Directive for loading forms into a single page app lost controller binding

Tags: binding, controller, directive

I'm creating a single page app using AngularJS. I have created a main page with a custom directive for loading a form URL. I want to change the the forms based on a variable in my controller. However, I lost my bindings once I compiled and linked the form from URL

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tradesman"  ng-controller="application" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
Hello {{applicant.name}}
<my-form name="formName">

</my-form>
</div>
```

```js
var tradesman = angular.module("tradesman")

tradesman.controller("application",function application($scope){
 $scope.formName="personals";
 $scope.applicant={};
 });

tradesman.directive("myForm",function($http,$compile){
  return {
   restrict:"E",
   scope:false,
   replace:true,
   
   link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    var url="http://tradesman.local/views/"+scope.formName+".html";
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
     scope.$watch(function(){
      element.html(response.data);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      });
    });
    
    
   }
  };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This has successfully loaded my personals page but lost the binding in that page. More over I want a new form to be loaded whenever I change my formName in controller.

What needs to be done to make form loading and binding work simultaneously